# Hamburger Menu jQuery HTML CSS unresponsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I began by watching this tutorial and following line by line until my code didn't seem to be responding the way the video showed it would. The problem I encountered is that my hamburger menu was n not responsive to the jQuery and I don't know which steps to take to fix it.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAnb1vmmg5A This is the first full website I am attempting to build but need a bit of help to get there. You don't have to help me, but if you choose to I would greatly appreciate it. All the best.

```js
$(document).ready(function ()){
    alert('check');
    $('.menu-btn').click(function(){
        $('navigation').toggleClass('active')
    });
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding 0 auto;
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
    text-align: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(laab2.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

header{
    width: fit-content 100%
    height: 2rem;
    padding: 2.6em;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 10;    
}

header .logo{
    float: left;
    position: fixed;  
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

header .menu-btn {
  float: right;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  color: black;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

#toggle:checked + .menu-btn{
    display: block;
}

.navigation{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0vh;
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 1.3s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navigation :hover{
    border-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

.navigation.active{
    height:100vh;

}

.navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 20vh;
}

.navigation ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.navigation ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 0px 20px;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: 1.5s;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover {
    border-color: rgb(255,255,255);

}

section{
    z-index: -99;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'poppins' sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h2{
    font-weight: 200;
}
p{
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>LAAB</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-top">
    <div class="logo" img src="#">
      <h2>LAAB </h2></div>
      <div class="menu-btn" div class="toggle">|||</div> 
      <!--script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.toggle').click(function()){
            $('.toggle').toggleClass('active')
          })
        })
      
      </script-->
    </header>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Welding</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fabrication</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>


      </ul>
    </nav>

    <section>
      <div class="text">
        <h2><Strong>"There is no limitation to fabrication"</Strong></h2>
      </div>

      
      <div class="text">

        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <p>Call Us | Email</p>


      </div>


    </section>
  
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code had a few syntax errors in the javaScript. I have added comments to show where you went wrong. I also slightly modifed the CSS to change the menu text colour (it was white).

See code below:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding 0 auto;
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
    text-align: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(laab2.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

header{
    width: fit-content 100%
    height: 2rem;
    padding: 2.6em;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 10;



}

header .logo{
    float: left;
    position: fixed;  
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
header .menu-btn {
  float: right;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  color: black;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;

}
#toggle:checked + .menu-btn{
    display: block;
}

.navigation{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0vh;
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 1.3s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navigation :hover{
    border-color: rgb(255,255,255);


}
.navigation.active{
 height:100vh;
 color:#000;

}
.navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 20vh;
}
.navigation ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.navigation ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    /* commented out below line because it wa smaking the text white and you couldn't see it */
   /*  color: rgb(255, 255, 255); */
    padding: 0px 20px;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: 1.5s;
}
.navigation ul li a:hover {
    border-color: rgb(255,255,255);

}

        section{
            z-index: -99;
            color: #fff;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-family: 'poppins' sans-serif;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        h2{
            font-weight: 200;
        }


        p{
            margin-top: 30px;
            color: white;
            letter-spacing: 2px;

            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="burger-style.css">
  <title>LAAB</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-top">
    <div class="logo" img src="#">
      <h2>LAAB </h2></div>
      <div class="menu-btn" div class="toggle">|||</div> 
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.toggle').click(function(){
            $('.toggle').toggleClass('active');
          });// minor but there was no semicolon
        }); // minor but there was no semicolon

      </script>
    </header>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Welding</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fabrication</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>


      </ul>
    </nav>

    <section>
      <div class="text">
        <h2><Strong>"There is no limitation to fabrication"</Strong></h2>
      </div>


      <div class="text">

        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <p>Call Us | Email</p>


      </div>


    </section>

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 // $(document).ready(function ()){ // too mnay brackets here, see line below for proper syntax
  $(document).ready(function (){
    //alert('check');
    $('.menu-btn').click(function(){
       // $('navigation').toggleClass('active') //navigation doesn't have a '.' in front which indicates its a class, also didn't have semicolon ';' at end of line 
  $('.navigation').toggleClass('active');
 });
// } // missing closing bracket and semicolon, see line below for correct syntax
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can see there are few syntax erros. I would recommend opening your page in Chrome or Firefox and check for errors.